# How to detect collision happened from up side game physics

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I check collision with this function:

```
function collision(wall, hero) {
  return (wall.x < hero.x + hero.width &&
          wall.x + wall.width > hero.x &&
          wall.y < hero.y + hero.height);
  // && wall.y + wall.height > hero.y);
}
```

But I want to know if the collision happened from up or side how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, keeping the function useful in an if: return false when no collision. Return "up" when collision from up, return "side" when collisiin from side. Both of these strings are truish. You can also do the same with numbers, giving them meaning, but it is not as readable. You can easily implement this in an if ladder for the different conditions, and you can either give precedence to one type of collision, or you can return for example "both" when there is collisiin from both directions. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you,

```
function collision(wall, hero) {
let returnVal = false;

returnVal = wall.x < hero.x + hero.width ? 1 : false
returnVal = wall.x + wall.width > hero.x ? 2 : false
returnVal = wall.y < hero.y + hero.height ? 3 : false
returnVal = wall.y + wall.height > hero.y ? 4 : false

return returnVal
```

}

I didnt check the logic. But my concept is use values for each side (Up = 1, Right = 2, Down = 3, Left = 4).

When you are checking collision use switch case for above values and do the relevant work. Hope this will help you.